# grails proper way to map a non domain class in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm, dns

If I have a domain class called `MyDomainClass` in grails that looks like:

```
class MyDomainClass {
    MyNonDomainClass nonDomainClass    
}
```

and MyNonDomainClass:

```
class MyNonDomainClass {
   String name
   int age   
}
```

will hibernate mappings be properly setup since `MyNonDomainClass` is a non domain class? Or do I need to explicitly specify the type, such as:

```
class MyDomainClass {
    def nonDomainClass
    static mapping = { nonDomainClass type: MyNonDomainClass }
}
```

Or will `MyNonDomainClass` not work as a type either since it's not a domain class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grails will not know how to handle this class, so you will need to implement a Hibernate's [UserType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html). An example can be found in [Hibernate's docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom-ut).

Having this class you can configure your type in `grails.gorm.default.mapping`. Example:

```
class MyNonDomainClassUserType implements UserType {
  ...
}
```

Config.groovy

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
  "user-type" type: MyNonDomainClassUserTye, class: MyNonDomainClass
}
```

With this config there's no need to change the domain class.